# C - How can i execute a method every X seconds?

Tags: c

Probably really trivial question, but:

Recently started working an open-source system - [janus-gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) and i am in a need to run a method every 1 second(checking if all users muted).

What are the options to do this in C?
Should i spawn a new thread?

Answer with an example would much appreciated!

Comment: Searching for a solution will be far more fruitful than asking for a solution. See [help] for the purpose/scope of SO

Comment: Too many issues about what sort of environment you have. Needing to run something at fairly coarse intervals (in computer terms) is a common enough requirement, but there are many ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up spawning a new thread and doing stuff that way.